# sp_notify_operator: The specified @operator_name does not exist (but it does!)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-mail

OK, so I think I'm going mad here! Here's where I am.

SQL Server 2008: I've set up Database Mail, and I've sent myself a test email. Simple, works fine.

I've created an operator, called 'Tom'. I've given it an email address (but nothing else).

However, when I run this command:

> EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_notify_operator @name=N'Tom',@subject=N'Test Database Message',@body=N'Testy Test Test'

...I get this:

> Msg 14262, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_verify_operator_identifiers, Line 51
>   The specified @operator_name ('Tom') does not exist.

Is that error message masking something else which I should be looking at? There's definately an operator shown in SSMS, but if there's a sproc which lists operators I'll happily run that to see if it's actually there.

I'm just kinda stuck as to where to go next. SQL Server seems convinced I don't exist!

Comment: sp_help_operator lists operators (use without specifying operator_name to get all operators) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188756.aspx

Comment: Thank you, that's great. I knew there was a way somewhere!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore this! There's a possibility that I was trying to execute sp_notify_operator whilst connected to the wrong server...the one without any operators....

Apologies!